# What is the most RESTful form of authentication? Who is using it?

Tags: web-services, authentication, rest, asp.net-web-api

**Duplicate:** this **must** be a duplicate of one of the questions that come up in the following [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest+authentication): Please close it as a duplicate if you agree, and add any answers to one of the other questions.

---

What is the most RESTful form of authentication? What websites use it? (so I can go look at the documentation).

Looking at some APIs that claim to be REST are really POX
(ex. Remember the Milk - http://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/api/methods/)

Comment: This **must** be a duplicate of one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest+authentication

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the 'most RESTful' form, but Amazon's S3 uses an authentication method which is documented [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?RESTAPI.html). Each request is signed, so there is no session to track on the backend, but you can still securely verify what user issued the request.

Comment: +1. This sort of makes sense. Is there a good hashing/crypto JavaScript lib that you'd recommend?

Comment: Not that I've used in production. I tried to go with this method for a project at work, but we ended up using Flex/amfphp instead. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

The *most* RESTful authentication method is probably [HTTP Basic](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#BasicAA). Because it has some significant weaknesses (replay attacks), most APIs tend to shy away from it.

Answer (score 1):

[Open Sourcery](http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/restful-authentication/) has a well-thought-out article on RESTful authentication.  Sounds like there are no awesome solutions right now beyond simple user/pass auth over SSL and then keeping auth info in subsequent request headers.